# Export table of lme4 anova results + effect sizes

Tags: r, linear-regression, lme4, mixed-models

I am trying to export a table with the results of a mixed ANOVA that I ran with `lme4`. This is the model. I want to export the ANOVA statistics plus respective eta square effect sizes. The format can be either html, or pdf, or even png.

It turned out to be a nightmare. Tried several libraries xtable, stargazer, apa, knitr, apatable. Nothing worked. Why is that? This is actually a trivial thing to do.

```
model <- lme4::lmer(avgAmplitude ~ stimulusAge*stimulusResponse*congruency*subjectType + (1|id), data=dataset)
anova_table <- anova(model)
avgAmplitude - continous
stimulusAge - factor (2, within)
stimulusResponse - factor (2, within)
congruency - factor (2, within)
subjectType - factor (2, between)
(1|id) - random effect
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not provide a reproducible form of your data here, so it is difficult to show you how to do this with your own model fit, but I have provided a worked example here as an example using the flextable package. First, I fit two mixed models and saved their ANOVA fit such as below:

```
#### Load Library ####
library(lmerTest)
library(flextable)

#### Fit Models ####
fit.1 <- lmer(Preference 
            ~ sens2 
            + Homesize 
            + (1 | Consumer),
            data=carrots,
            REML = F)

fit.2 <- lmer(Preference 
              ~ sens2 
              + Homesize 
              + (1 + sens2 | Consumer),
              data=carrots,
              REML = F)

#### ANOVA ####
aov <- anova(fit.1,fit.2)

#### Flextable ####
flextable(aov)
```

Running this as is will give you a quick table you can view in R and export from the Viewer tab as a different format:

[image]

However, this tends to look funky when you do this. You can directly add a flextable to an RMarkdown file and directly get HTML or pdf formatting. That said, if you are just interested in the table, you can use the `save_as_image` function with whatever format you want. Make sure in the `path` argument you specify your working directory as well as the file extension. Here I use .png.

```
#### Flextable ####
install.packages("webshot2")
flex <- flextable(aov) 
save_as_image(flex,
              path = "C:/Users/DELL/Dropbox/My PC (DESKTOP-SUOCLVS)/Desktop/Research Tools/R Directory/image.png")
```

The saved object can be found in your directory thereafter and you can add it to a doc of your choosing like so:

[image]